# Image Button does not hide on page load

Tags: asp.net, imagebutton, directcast

I used code below to hide template field Imagebutton on pageload but it DOES NOT work,
Thanks in advance:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            Dim ImageButton1 As ImageButton = DirectCast(GridView1.FindControl("ImageButton1"), ImageButton)
            If User.Identity.Name.Substring(InStr(User.Identity.Name, "\")).ToUpper = "User1" Then
                ImageButton1.Visible = False
            End If
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have `binding grid before and it has rows`. *Find the ImageButton in some row of grid instead of find within gridview*. The `if` condition you have seems to never get true, as you are comparing string after ToUpper with a string that is not in upper case, `Change User1 to USER1` As you are using ToUpper.

**Change**

```
 Dim ImageButton1 As ImageButton = DirectCast(GridView1.FindControl("ImageButton1"), ImageButton) 
 If User.Identity.Name.Substring(InStr(User.Identity.Name, "\")).ToUpper = "User1" Then
            ImageButton1.Visible = False
 End If
```

**To**

```
   Dim ImageButton1 As ImageButton = DirectCast(GridView1.Rows(0).FindControl("ImageButton1"), ImageButton)
 If User.Identity.Name.Substring(InStr(User.Identity.Name, "\")).ToUpper = "USER1" Then
       ImageButton1.Visible = False
 End If
```

**Iterating whole grid by loop**

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
 Dim ImageButton1 As ImageButton = DirectCast(row.FindControl("ImageButton1"), ImageButton)
     If User.Identity.Name.Substring(InStr(User.Identity.Name, "\")).ToUpper = "USER1" Then
           ImageButton1.Visible = False
     End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks Adil for your quick response, I tried ur code n it worked but only for the first row(index=0). Can you include the code for binding grid on pageload?

Comment: You need to iterate the whole grid using loop, check my updated answer.